# What is a systematic approach to debug intermittently failing specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, capybara

I have four tests in my Capybara/Rspec suite that keep failing (a real problem for CI deployment).

The worst thing, these tests are failing intermittently, and often only when the entire suite is run, making it difficult to debug.

They are all ajax requests, either submitting a remote form or clicking a remote link, followed by `expect(page).to have_content 'My Flash Message'`.

These tests even fail intermittently within the same test cycle. For example, I have several models that behave similarly, so I am iterating through them to test.

```
e.g., 
['Country', 'State', 'City'].each do |object|
  let(:target) { create object.to_sym }
  it 'runs my frustrating test' do 
  end
end
```

Sometimes country fails, sometimes state, sometimes everything passes.

I have tried adding `wait: 30` to the expect statement. I have tried adding `sleep 30` before the expect statement. I'm still getting intermittent passes.

There is quite a bit of information out there describing finicky ajax tests, but I have not found much about how to debug and fix these kinds of problems.

I'm really grateful for any advise or pointers from others, before I pull all my hair out!!

## UPDATE

Thank you for all these excellent responses. It's been useful to see that others have grappled with similar issues, and that I'm not alone.

So, is there a solution?

The suggestions to use debugging tools such pry, byebug, Poltergeist's debug feature (thanks @Jay-Ar Polidario, @TomWalpole) have been useful to confirm what I thought I already knew — namely, and as suggested by @BM5K) that the features work consistently in the browser, and the errors lie within the tests.

I experimented with with adjusting timeouts and retries (@Jay-Ar Polidario, @BM5K), and while an improvement these were still not a consistent fix. More importantly, this approach felt like patching holes rather than a proper fix, and so I was not entirely comfortable.

Ultimately I went with a major rewrite of these tests. This has entailed breaking up multi-step features, and setting up and testing each step individually. While purists may claim this is not truly testing from the user's perspective, there is sufficient overlap between each test that I'm comfortable with the result.

In going through this process, I did notice that all of these errors were related to "clicking on things, or filling forms", as @BoraMa suggested. Though in this case the experience was reversed — we had adopted `.trigger('click')` syntax because capybara + poltergeist was reporting errors clicking on elements using `click_link` or `find(object).click`, and it was these tests that were problematic.

To avoid these problems I've removed JS from the tests as much as possible. i.e., testing the majority of the feature without JS enabled, and then creating very short, targeted JS specs to test specific JS responses, features or user feedback.

So there is not really one single fix. A major refactoring that, in all honesty, probably needed to happen and was a valuable exercise. The tests have lost some features by by breaking everything up into individual tests, but as a whole this has made the tests easier to read and maintain.

There are still a couple of tests that are occasionally showing red, and will need some more work. But overall a great improvement.

Thank you all for the great guidance, and reassuring me that interactions in the testing environment could be the root cause.

Comment: Is the error always showing up the same? Just to have an idea, could you add a sample error? We had intermittent failing specs also before but we found out that it was another independent bug that was causing it.

Comment: Always the same. I'm either expecting flash content `Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "#{target.model_name.human} was flagged!"        expected to find text "Country was flagged!" in ......` or a selector `Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector "a.unflag-btn" expected to find css "a.unflag-btn" but there were no matches`

Comment: `save_and_open_page` does not reveal anything obvious. and these tests pass when run insolation, and intermittently with the suite.

Comment: What JS driver are you using for Capybara? Poltergeist? Selenium?

Comment: I'm using Poltergeist

Comment: For Poltergeist, you may try using its [debug feature](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#user-content-remote-debugging-experimental) just in case you might spot something that is causing the intermittent failing test.

Comment: If you think there are no problems with the client-side, the next place to look at might be the server-side (i.e. do you not have any random variables, such as the usage of Faker gem?). If this test is a local connection (that it is not a remote AJAX test), then there should be no connection problems as it is local, and therefore I could only think that is either/both the server-side and/or client-side which causes the intermittent error.

Comment: For server-side debugging, I usually just insert `byebug` right after the line where you have loaded the page. then you could just inspect the `page` object, and its methods.

Comment: show your actual 'frustrating test' code and the actual error you get and we may be able to point out why it's flaky - you could also make sure you've turned on debug: true and js_errors: true in the poltergeist driver - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - and post the log that creates

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario thanks for these suggestions. I have used byebug and pry, but these have not unearthed anything. Though this may be due to the temperamental nature of this bug. Poltergeist debug is new — thanks for this tip — though also has not revealed anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intermittently failing tests are a pain to troubleshoot, but there are some things you can do to make life easier. First would be to remove any looping or shared examples. Explicitly stating each expectation should make it more clear which example combination is failing (or make it even more obvious that it is indeed random).

Over the course of several runs, track which tests are failing. Are they all in the same context group?

Are you mixing and matching javascript tests and non-javascript tests? If you are, you may be running into database issues (I've seen problems caused by switching database cleaner strategies mid context block).

Make sure you consider any parent context blocks the tests are in.

And if none of that narrows down your search, use a gem that allows you to retry failing tests.

I used [respec-retry](https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry) in the past, but have found it to be unreliable lately. I've switched to [rspec-repeat](https://github.com/rstacruz/rspec-repeat). I usually leave these off in development (configured for 1 try) and run with multiple tries on CI (usually 3). That way I can get a feel for which tests are wobbly locally, but not let those tests break my build (unless they fail consistently).

TL;DR

Most of the intermittently failing tests I encounter have a lot of moving pieces (rails, capybara, database cleaner, factory girl, phantomjs, rspec  just to name a few). If the code is tested AND the specs frequently pass AND the feature consistently works in the browser chances are some interaction in your testing environment is the root cause of the intermittent failures. If you can't track that down, retry the failing specs a couple of times.

Comment: rspec-repeat is nice, thank you! now I can enjoy not receiving alerts in the middle of the night when some random selenium test decides to fail for no reason at all.

Answer (score 5):

Let me bring out story too :). Recently, we also tried to hunt and fix the issues with our intermittently failing tests under similar setup (Poltergeist, JS tests). The tests failed more probably when the whole test suite was run than individually but in about one third of time the whole suite succeeded. It was just a couple of tests from the suite, about 10, that randomly failed, others seemed to run OK all the time.

First we made sure the tests were not failing due to db truncation issues, leftover records etc. We made screenshots upon the moment of failure to verify that the page looked correct.

After a lot more searching we noticed that all of the remaining failing tests deal with **clicking on things, or filling forms** while there were jQuery animations and other dynamic operations frequently used on the pages. This lead us to this [Poltergeist issue](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/530) which helped us greatly in the end. It turns out that Poltergeist, when clicking on a button or dealing with form inputs, tries to maximally mimic the normal user which can lead to problems when the inputs / links are animated.

A way to recognize that this was indeed an issue for us was that we could successfully `find` the element on the page but the browser was unable to click on it.

We ended up using a not very clean solution - we have rewritten some capybara helpers for clicking and interacting with forms to use `find` and `trigger` internally:

```
# override capybara methods as they react badly with animations 
# (click/action is not registered then and test fails)
# see https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/530
def click_button(locator, *options)
  find_button(locator, *options).trigger(:click)
end

def click_link(locator, *options)
  find_link(locator, *options).trigger(:click)
end

def choose(locator, *options)
  find(:radio_button, locator, *options).trigger(:click)
end

def check(locator, *options)
  find(:checkbox, locator, *options).trigger(:click)
end
```

This approach may lead to some unexpected problems because now you'll be able to click on things in your tests even if they are e.g. overlapped by a modal div or when they are not fully visible on the page. But after reading carefully the comments on the github issue, we decided that this was the way to go for us.

Since then, we have only very occasional test failures which seem to be related to another Poltergeist [timeouts issue](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/713). But the failures are so rare that we don't feel the urge to look further - the tests are finally reliable enough.

Comment: You're right. I remember now that we had some issue with this as well regarding the `trigger(:click)`. Good stuff :)

Comment: A better solution is to disable animations in test mode, rather than risking triggering events on elements a user could never click.

Comment: We actually switched off everything we could but now that you say it, we could probably [do more](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fx.off/) (I guess I'll try that). On the other hand it's always about balancing the limited test environment vs. real user experience, so switching off animations does not guarantee that everything works for the user either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that there is no changing variable in both server (Rails), and client (JS) side. You may try the following if it will work. We used this for some similar problem we had.

spec/support/wait_for_ajax.rb

```
# ref: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
    sleep(1) # ensure just because above doesn't always work
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end
```

spec/features/YOUR_SPEC.rb

```
Rspec.feature 'My Feature Test', type: :feature do
  ['Country', 'State', 'City'].each do |object|
    let(:target) { create object.to_sym }
    it 'runs my frustrating test' do 
      find('#my-div').click
      wait_for_ajax
    end
  end
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
# ..
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ..
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
  # ..
end
# ..
```

Comment: 99% of the time wait_for_ajax is just a workaround for badly written tests, couple that with the sleep(1) inserted in your method and this is not something that should be recommended.

Comment: yes this is not really recommended. however, would you be interested in reading further my reference link. He discussed there this use-case for race conditions.

Comment: Read your link, and yes there are rare cases, but they really are rare.  As the last section of that link states, if you're not indicating in any visual way that an action has completed then it's most likely a bad UI, and if you are you should be waiting for that with Capybara rather than using wait_for_ajax -  The one place wait_for_ajax was really justified was for ajax requests that continued after the end of a test (and therefore could cause DB issues during cleanup) and that issue should have been fixed with Capybara 2.7 which waits for them to finish automatically.